# $L_2$ norm of product of two vectors

Tags: machine-learning, standardization, distance, euclidean, random-vector

Let's assume we have two matrices $A^{d\times 1}$ and $B^{1 \times e}$, and we define their product as $C^{d\times e}$. Assuming $A,B$ are real valued with all entries in $[-1,1]$.

I can intuitively see that the $L_2$ norm of $C$, where the norm is taken after flattening the matrix so we have one row and $d \times e$ columns, would be larger than the individual $L_2$ norms of $A$ and $B$ taken in the same way, because $C$ is much higher dimensional than $A$ and $B$. But, I was wondering if there is a formal result to support this and under what assumptions, i.e. the minimum size of $A$ and $B$ and any constraints on their scale etc.

Comment: There are at least two different notions of $L^2$ norm for matrices: the Frobenius norm $\|A\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i, j} \left|A_{i, j}\right|^2}$ and the operator norm $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \|A x\|_2$ (where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the usual $L^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$). Which one do you mean here?

Comment: This question seems to contain some inconsistencies which need clarification and edits. By "vector" would you mean *matrix*?  By "dot product" would you mean *matrix product*?  And in what sense is "$C$ ... higher dimensional than $A$"? If, for instance, $n=1,d=10^6,$ and $e=1,$ then $A$ has a million components and $C$ has just $1$ component!

Comment: @ArtemMavrin,@whuber, sorry, edited for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p \ge 1,$ the $L_p$ norm of a vector $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is defined to be

$$\|x\|_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

Notice that with $A^\prime=(a_i)$ and $B=(b_j),$ $C = (c_{ij}) = (a_i b_j).$  Thus

$$\|C\|_p^p = \sum_{ij} |c_{ij}|^p = \sum_{ij} |a_ib_j|^p = \sum_{ij} |a_i|^p |b_j|^p = \sum_i |a_i|^p \sum_j |b_j|^p = \|A\|_p^p \|B\|_p^p.$$

Taking $p^\text{th}$ roots shows *the norms are equal.*  The case $p=2$ answers the question.  There's no need to restrict the values of $a_i$ and $b_j$ and there's no restriction on the dimensions of the vectors, either.  (The demonstration extends to all $p\ne 0,$ but for $p\lt 1$ this is no longer a norm.)

Comment: sorry, one more question, this only implies that the product of individual norms is equal to norm of the product. Can we say anything about the comparison of individual $||A||$ and individual $||B||$ with $||C||$?

Comment: Yes, easily: the comparison of $\|A\|$ with $\|C\|$ is determined by $\|B\|$: if the latter is less than unity, then $C$ has smaller norm than $A$; otherwise, $C$ does not have smaller norm than $A.$